# Pass API key / auth information from HttpOperationHandler to API class in WCF4 webservice

Tags: .net, wcf, api, rest

I'm currently developing an WCF4 based REST webservice. Most calls don't need authorization, but some do, so my plan is to implement an *RequireAuthorization* attribute that handles API key authorization for some calls.

After reading [Implementing an Authorization Attribute for WCF Web API](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/10/19/implementing-an-authorization-attribute-for-wcf-web-api.aspx) I implemented an HttpOperationHandler that handles the API key validation in the *OnHandle* method and added it to the RequestHandlers in the service configuration.

Basically this works fine, but I need to pass the user info I extracted in the AuthOperationHandler to the service, but I can't find any information on this.

Can anyone help?

```
public class ServiceConfiguration : WebApiConfiguration
{
    public ServiceConfiguration()
    {
        RequestHandlers = (c, e, od) => {
            var authorizeAttribute = od.Attributes.OfType<RequireAuthorizationAttribute>().FirstOrDefault();
            if (authorizeAttribute != null)
            {
                c.Add(new AuthOperationHandler(authorizeAttribute));
            }
        };

        CreateInstance = (serviceType, context, request) => RepositoryFactory.GetInstance(serviceType);
    }
}

public class AuthOperationHandler : HttpOperationHandler<HttpRequestMessage, HttpRequestMessage>
{
    protected override HttpRequestMessage OnHandle(HttpRequestMessage input)
    {
        // API Key validation here
        var user = RetrieveUserByApiKey(input);

        return input;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found a solution to this, but it does come with a caveat.

The way I did it was for my operation handler to return some form of custom authentication state class instead of a HttpResponsemessage - in my case I used an AuthenticationTicket.

```
public class AuthOperationHandler : HttpOperationHandler<HttpRequestMessage, AuthenticationTicket>
{
    protected override AuthenticationTicket OnHandle(HttpRequestMessage input)
    {
        var ticket = RetrieveAuthenticationTicket(input);

        return ticket;
    }
}
```

And the AuthenticationTicket class just stores the account ID.

```
    public class AuthenticationTicket
    {
        public AuthenticationTicket(int accountId)
        {
            AccountId = accountId;
        }

        public int AccountId { get; set; }
    }
```

Then in your service method you add an AuthenticationTicket as a parameter and this will be populated for you by the operation handler.

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "people", Method = "GET")]
    HttpResponseMessage<IList<Person>> LoadPeople(AuthenticationTicket ticket);
```

You can then use the ticket in your method implementation.

However, this acts a bit funny with POST, PUT and DELETE operations if you need to use an additional parameter, like so:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "people", Method = "PUT")]
    HttpResponseMessage AddPerson(AuthenticationTicket ticket, Person person);
```

You'll get an exception along the following lines:

> The HttpOperationHandlerFactory is unable to determine the input
>   parameter that should be associated with the request message content
>   for service operation 'AddPerson'. If the operation does not expect
>   content in the request message use the HTTP GET method with the
>   operation. Otherwise, ensure that one input parameter either has it's
>   IsContentParameter property set to 'True' or is a type that is
>   assignable to one of the following: HttpContent, ObjectContent`1,
>   HttpRequestMessage or HttpRequestMessage`1.

The solution I found (not sure whether it's right) is to wrap the resource in a HttpRequestMessage like so:

```
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "people", Method = "PUT")]
    HttpResponseMessage UpdatePerson(AuthenticationTicket ticket, HttpRequestMessage<Person> request);
```

Then in your method use the following to retrieve the Person:

```
var person = request.Content.ReadAsAsync<Person>().Result;
```

Hope this helps, it works for me.  But I'm still learning myself to be honest, so there may be better ways of doing it.